# Getting property does not exist on type error in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I am trying to make a collapsible menu in my header component and I am having trouble with correct JSON formating in my angular project. I keep getting this error:

> Error: src/app/components/header/header.component.html:48:49 - error
> TS2339: Property 'sublinks' does not exist on type '{ title: string;
> collapsed: boolean; links: { title: string; url: string; sublinks: {
> title: string; url: string; }[]; }[]; }'.
>
> 48                 <li *ngFor="let sublink of item.sublinks"
> class="sublink">

I can't seem to resolve this error on my own and would like some help.

**My HTML template is this:**

```
<li *ngFor="let item of navigationItems; let i = index" class="link">
            <a [href]="item.url" class="main-wrapper">{{ item.title }}</a>
            <a class="d-inline-block main-wrapper" (click)="toggleCollapse(i)" role="button" [attr.aria-expanded]="!item.collapsed" [attr.aria-controls]="'navCollapse_' + i">
              <img *ngIf="item.collapsed" src="./assets/img/icons/plus.svg" alt="plus-icon" class="ms-3">
              <img *ngIf="!item.collapsed" src="./assets/img/icons/minus.svg" alt="minus-icon" class="ms-3">
            </a>
            <div [id]="'navCollapse_' + i" class="collapse link-collapse main-collapse" [class.show]="!item.collapsed">
              <ul class="sublink-wrapper">
                <li *ngFor="let sublink of item.sublinks" class="sublink">
                  <a [href]="sublink.url">{{ sublink.title }}</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
```

**My TS code is this:**

```
export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor() { }

  navigationState: string = 'out';
  
  navigationItems = [
    {
      title: 'Lorem ipsum',
      collapsed: true,
      links: [
        {
          title: 'Lorem ipsum 1',
          url: 'some-url',
          sublinks: [
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 1.1', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 1.2', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 1.3', url: 'some url' }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: 'Lorem ipsum 2',
          url: 'some-url',
          sublinks: [
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 2.1', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 2.2', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 2.3', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 2.4', url: 'some url' }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: 'Lorem ipsum 3',
          url: 'some-url',
          sublinks: [
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 3.1', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 3.2', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 3.3', url: 'some url' }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: 'Lorem ipsum 4',
          url: 'some-url',
          sublinks: [
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 4.1', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 4.2', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 4.3', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 4.4', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 4.5', url: 'some url' }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ];

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  toggleCollapse(index: number): void {
    this.navigationItems[index].collapsed = !this.navigationItems[index].collapsed;
  }

}
```

Comment: quite clearly, `sublinks` is a property of object in the `links` array - I see your code also attempts to access `item.links.url` - which won't work since `item.links` is an array

Comment: @JaromandaX yes the item.links.url was a mistake, i want it to show item.url

Comment: but the objects in `navigationItems` array don't have an url property - I think you've missed a level of array in your `navigationItems` ... navigationItems is an Array of Objects, with a property `links` which is an Array, of objects, each having a sublinks property which is an Array ... I'd expect to see 3 nested `*ngFor` to access the sublinks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jaromanda X says correct, `sublinks` is a property of object in the `links`. So you should iterate over 'links' first. And totally you must have 3 `*ngFor` (not 2): over `navigationItems`, then `links`, then `sublinks. Also you can consider removing` *ngIf` and use ternar operator for src and alt. So finally I'd expect to see something like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of navigationItems; let i = index" class="link">
      <a class="main-wrapper" (click)="toggleCollapse(i)" role="button" [attr.aria-expanded]="!item.collapsed" [attr.aria-controls]="'navCollapse_' + i">
        {{ item.title }}
        <img [src]="item.collapsed ? './assets/img/icons/plus.svg' : './assets/img/icons/minus.svg'" [alt]="item.collapsed ? 'plus-icon' : 'minus-icon'" class="ms-3">
      </a>
      <div [id]="'navCollapse_' + i" class="collapse link-collapse main-collapse" [class.show]="!item.collapsed">
        <ul class="sublink-wrapper">
          <li *ngFor="let link of item.links" class="sublink">
            <a [href]="link.url">{{ link.title }}</a>
            <ul *ngIf="!item.collapsed" class="sub-sublink-wrapper">
              <li *ngFor="let sublink of link.sublinks" class="sub-sublink">
                <a [href]="sublink.url">{{ sublink.title }}</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
constructor() { }

  navigationState: string = 'out';
  
  navigationItems:any = [
    {
      title: 'Lorem ipsum',
      collapsed: true,
      links: [
        {
          title: 'Lorem ipsum 1',
          url: 'some-url',
          sublinks: [
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 1.1', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 1.2', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 1.3', url: 'some url' }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: 'Lorem ipsum 2',
          url: 'some-url',
          sublinks: [
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 2.1', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 2.2', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 2.3', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 2.4', url: 'some url' }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: 'Lorem ipsum 3',
          url: 'some-url',
          sublinks: [
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 3.1', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 3.2', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 3.3', url: 'some url' }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: 'Lorem ipsum 4',
          url: 'some-url',
          sublinks: [
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 4.1', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 4.2', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 4.3', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 4.4', url: 'some url' },
            { title: 'Lorem ispum 4.5', url: 'some url' }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ];

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  toggleCollapse(index: number): void {
    this.navigationItems[index].collapsed = !this.navigationItems[index].collapsed;
  }

}
```

```html
<li *ngFor="let item of navigationItems; let i = index" class="link">
    <a [href]="item?.url" class="main-wrapper">{{ item.title }}</a>
    <a class="d-inline-block main-wrapper" (click)="toggleCollapse(i)" role="button" [attr.aria-expanded]="!item.collapsed" [attr.aria-controls]="'navCollapse_' + i">
      <img *ngIf="item.collapsed" src="./assets/img/icons/plus.svg" alt="plus-icon" class="ms-3">
      <img *ngIf="!item.collapsed" src="./assets/img/icons/minus.svg" alt="minus-icon" class="ms-3">
    </a>
    <div [id]="'navCollapse_' + i" class="collapse link-collapse main-collapse" [class.show]="!item.collapsed">
      <ul class="sublink-wrapper">
        <li *ngFor="let sublink of item?.sublinks" class="sublink">
          <a [href]="sublink.url">{{ sublink.title }}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
```